# How to debug a spreadsheet custom function in google script?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am writing a custom function to be used in a spreadsheet and I would like to be able to at least display some data. Few things seem to work, for example `Browser.msgBox` doesn't find the appropriate permissions.

Breakpoints don't interrupt execution.

I had some hope for this code

```
function test() {
  var s = "test"
  Logger.log(s)
  return s + s
}
```

But when I set a cell in the spreadsheet to `"=test()"` the cell properly shows the value "testtest" but when I return to the script editor and use view>execution transcript or `view>logs` I don't see anything.

Perhaps this logging goes to a special file somewhere?

Comment: Try `Spreadsheet.toast()`.

Comment: @Mogsdad: [trying to show a toast from a custom functions doesn't work](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280131639) either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a custom function as a formula, it can be evaluated and re-evaluated at many times. Therefore, it is not appropriate to fill up the Logging output or the Execution Transcript with this. If you want to debug, you must run (or debug) the script manually from the script editor.

Take an example, where you have two custom functions - `f1()` and `f2()`
And say, in cell `A1`, you enter the formula `=f1()` and in `A2`, you enter `=f2(A1)`. 
In such a case, both the cells will be re-evaluated. So what should the logger output show ?

Comment: Thanks. I have checkmarked this. Other newbies like me might benefit from some additional advice on how to test a custom function with arguments. One obvious solution is to create a "tester" function that calls the function to be tested providing an argument.

Comment: "it is not appropriate to fill up the Logging output or the Execution Transcript"... that's exactly what happens actually. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258460/how-to-debug-a-spreadsheet-custom-function-in-google-script/76162471#76162471).

Answer (score 1):

1. In your Google Sheet, go to <kbd>Extensions -> Apps Script</kbd>
2. In the sidebar choose <kbd>≡ -> Executions</kbd>
3. This tab contains the history of all scripts runs. Click the most recent run and you'll see the logs output via [`console.*`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console).

[image: Executions in Apps Script]